# How to verify is an array of cells is null in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an insertion into an array of cells, but only when that cell is empty.

In my case, that would mean `null` because I initialize an empty char array, and I want to insert only when the cell is empty (`null`).

The test: `if grid[i][j] == null` does not work, I get `"== cannot be applied to 'char', null"`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: A primitive type will never be null.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the declaration of the grid variable. Without this information, other people can only guess what is your issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "null" character is `'\0'`, so you can compare if `grid[i][j] == '\0'`.

The literal `null` is for reference types, which `char` is not.

Answer (score 5):

Primitive arrays such as your `char[][]` can't contain `null`. Only object arrays can hold nulls. You could convert your array to `Character[][]` instead.

Thanks to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) your existing code should work just fine, but now you can actually put nulls in it.

Answer (score 5):

> In my case that would mean null because I initialize an empty char array

Incorrect. The default value of a `char` is `'\0'`, e.g. `new char[3][4]` creates an outer arrays of 3 sub-arrays, and each sub-array contains 4 `'\0'` values.

So, your `if` statement should be:

```
if (grid[i][j] == '\0')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the Character type so that you would have null available in case you care about having null char as different from null.

You can use wrapper types such as Integer or Double to achieve the same effect with other primitives.